# Why does Window geometry change when migrating from VS2010 to VS2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, winapi, visual-studio-2017

I have a large Win API C++ Application that i recently moved from Visual Studio 2010 to 2017. Application compiles, links and runs now, but i find that the window borders are about 2 pixels larger than before.

This is a problem as we implemented docking windows long time ago with 100% own code. Although all sizes are retrieved from the OS using GetSystemMetrics etc. this turned out to need some more specific alignment. It took a lot of development time when developing (for Windows 2000) and retargeting later for Windows 7. Furthermore we have some small windows and the thicker frames just waste space.

So i installed the Windows [SDK 7.1](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8279) and was able after some tweaks to install that. But i am not able to choose 7.1 in the project settings. Typing in that in the project settings results in

> error MSB8036: The Windows SDK version 7.1 was not found.

Although I find a directory named:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1
```

Also when trying to re-target the Project, the SDK 7.1 is not listed.
I did a lot of googling and found [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/e19634d8-f635-4ed0-b8d7-45b64ccbd6fa/windows-sdk-7-in-visual-studio-2017?forum=visualstudiogeneral) and [that](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/c5d4ab9e-f508-42f8-ad27-b5f4fa4d7f97/windows-sdk-in-vs-2017?forum=visualstudiogeneral) but no substantial answer. msdn is horrible.

Questions (obsolet, see below):

- Is it possible to use VC 2017 with Windows 7 SDK? How?
- Is there possibly a different way to keep the geometry used with VC2010?

**EDIT**:
I don't think that this is a duplicate of [Dialog border different after porting code from Visual Studio 6 to Visual Studio 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772651/dialog-border-different-after-porting-code-from-visual-studio-6-to-visual-studio) although the link is quite helpful. It turned out, that different values are returned for `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFRAME)`. So far I do not see a substantial explanation for that. Please see my own answer and comments.

So let me **update the question**: 
Why does the value returned from `GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFRAME)` change when upgrading from VC2010 to VC2017?

What is the root cause?

Comment: Just retarget your project to use windows 10 SDK that comes with Visual Studio. Note that it will still allow you to build applications for Windows 7 just as fine.

Comment: That wont save the geometry problems.

Comment: Geometry problems are probably caused by some bugs in your code or system changes, not by wrong SDK version. Note that applications (typically) will still perform the same API calls regardless of the SDK used to built it.

Comment: *Is it possible to use VC 2017 with Windows 7 SDK?* - of course yes. *How?* - simply set include and lib paths to this sdk

Comment: are this not dpiaware problem ?

Comment: @VTT: The geometry definitely has changed, I dont know about a way to influence border wisth of plain windows. All i want is the same behavior as with VC2010 but the new compiler and IDE.

Comment: @RbMm Does changing the directories have the same effect as switching "Widnows SDK version" in the project settings? Wont that mix up?

Comment: i don't know about "Widnows SDK version" (whats is this and where), but you need simply set proper include and lib paths, where compiler and linker must look. this at all not depend from sdk.

Comment: Metrics returned by `GetSystemMetrics` and related functions are not SDK based, they are system-settings based. Stuff like frame border thickness or caption height can vary from system to system. You should actually tune them to different values on your test system to see whether your application can handle geometry changes properly.

Comment: In Visual Studio IDE, in the project settings you can set "Windows SDK version" in the general tab. I dont know what that does in deep.

Comment: however sdk only set of windows api definitions. doubt that something changed if you simply begin use another sdk - and so what ? this absolute not depend from compiler and linker. and of course from vs itself. may be you change manifest

Comment: So you are saying the cause is not in the SDK Version? I did nothing more than upgrading the compiler. Same machine etc. the maifest file did not change. What may be the cause?

Comment: *upgrading the compiler.* - you forget about linker too. but this is 100% not depend from both, and from sdk too. exist only 1 way - debug code

Comment: SDK seems unlikely to be the cause. Try debugging. Always the first port of call when you don't understand why your program doesn't behave the way you expect.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to use VC 2017 with Windows 7 SDK? How?

Yes, but I doubt this is the solution to your main problem.

> Is there possibly a different way to keep the geometry used with VC2010?

Yes, just change the minimum subsystem version to pre-Vista value, like 5.01 (for Windows XP 32-bit). For some reason, 5.1 will yield the same result too; the resulting EXE would be the same.

**When Win32 Subsystem Version is 6.0 or above, there is a behavior change regarding the window border size.** Though I am not aware of where Microsoft has documented about this.

[image: Prove that Subsystem version matters]

If you still have Windows 7, the difference is also obvious when you are using Windows Basic theme, as shown in this screenshot:

[image: Diff subsystem diff border]

Screenshot added by RED SOFT ADAIR:
[image]

Comment: The subsystem version for Windows XP is 5.01, not 5.1.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that answers. I found that this can be set in the linker options of Visual Studio in the field "Minimum Required Version". I added a screen shot to your answer if you dont mind.

Comment: See also this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30960872/how-to-properly-set-target-os-version-when-building-a-library-on-windows-using-v

Answer (score 2):

It turned out that the problem was as described here:
https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/eaae1445-264d-487f-aba1-52dfc8abdfe4/getsystemmetrics-difference-in-return-value-for-the-same-input?forum=windowssdk

The value returned for GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME) changed with VS 2013.

```
In VS2010 (Window 8.1) 
GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME); // 8 pixels 
In VS2013 (Window 8.1, same PC) 
GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYFRAME); // 4 pixels
```

In VC2013 and later the same result will be returned using

```
GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME) + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXPADDEDBORDER);
```

My windows still had the same frame size. I miss interpreted the root cause.

Still i do not understand how this can happen. By my understanding GetSystemMetrics is a function of the Windows OS. How can this function behave different when changing the compiler? I guess this IS part of the Windows SDK?

By the way, i found, that i *can* select "Windows 7.1" as the Platform Toolset, but not for the SDK (as i was thinking).

All this is confusing. Can anybody point out the differences and the junctions between SDK and Toolset?

**EDIT:**
I made a little sample program to prove this:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv)
{
    printf("GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME) returns: %d\n", GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXFRAME));
    return 0;
}
```

Compiling with VC2010 results in "8".

Compiling with VC2017 results in "4".

Even if i choose "dont upgrade" for the SDK when migrating to VC2017.
If you dont believe it - try yourself.

If you have any more insights to that - you're welcome. I give you a 500 points bounty!

Comment: It is *very* unlikely for a system call to return different values based on the IDE used to author and compile your source code. I'm fairly confident, that the issue is a different one.

Comment: what is "VCxxx" at all in this context ? the result of `GetSystemMetrics` can not depend from this. but it can depend from - are your application dpi aware

Comment: VC stands for Visual Studio

Comment: @IInspectable. It definitely does. See my updated answer - and thanks to all contributors!

Comment: It's not going to be the compiler. Something like the manifest is the likely cause.

Comment: Check your project Minimum Subsystem Version. I guess your VS2010 one is not 6.0, but your VS2017 is 6.0.

Comment: It may be the same issue as here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772651/dialog-border-different-after-porting-code-from-visual-studio-6-to-visual-studio

Comment: @David Heffernan: Try yourself. It takes a few minutes.

Comment: The funny thing here is that you put the [mcve] in an answer rather than the question